# Native linking failed, while installing in Firebase Analytics in Xamarin.Forms (iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Anyone implemented firebase `Analytics`, `Crashlytics` and `Performace Monitoring` in Xamarin.Forms 
while installing `Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics` Nuget I'm Getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rolling down a version or two?

Comment: Done them all and it's quite simple you will need a book and pen though, Check all the dependencies and note down the correct versions then find a common ground for all these NuGet packages and then install those!

Comment: Follow the error message to review the error logs and find out if there is any nuget package confits or missing.

Comment: Thanks for your people's reply. I need to implement those thinks any reference?

Answer (score 2):

I use the Analytics and crashlytics stably in my xf app with the following sample versions:

XF: No package

Android:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics" Version="60.1142.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics" Version="2.9.4.4"/>
```

iOS:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics" Version="5.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics" Version="3.14.0" />
```

Comment: Could you share the reference which do you use? or Any blog code sample

Comment: There is no blog or reference, I found the most stable version of the packages by changing up and down the version number.